# SQL query normalize multiple row values into one row one column field

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Maybe the title of the question is not the appropiate but here is the explanation:

I have the following tables:

[image]

There are only 5 benefit codes available:

[image]

So, one employee can have associated 1 to 5 benefits, but also employees without any benefit.

What I need to return in a query is a list of employees with a coded column for the benefits associated, like the following example:

[image]

So the column "**benefits**" is a coded column from the associated benefits of the employee.

If Peter has associated **Medical** and **Education** benefits then the coded value for "benefits" column should be as shown in the table "01001", where 0 means no association and 1 means associaton.

Right now im doing the follogin and is working but takes too long to process and Im sure there is a better way and faster:

```
SELECT emp.employee_id, emp.name, emp.lastname, 
CASE WHEN lif.benefitcode IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE '1' END +
CASE WHEN med.benefitcode IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE '1' END +
CASE WHEN opt.benefitcode IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE '1' END +
CASE WHEN uni.benefitcode IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE '1' END +
CASE WHEN edu.benefitcode IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE '1' END as benefits
FROM employee emp
-- life
LEFT JOIN ( 
     SELECT c.benefitcode, c.employee_id
     FROM employee_benefit c
     WHERE c.isactive = 1
     and c.benefitcode = 'lf'
) lif on lif.employee_id = emp.employee_id
-- medical
LEFT JOIN ( 
     SELECT c.benefitcode, c.employee_id
     FROM employee_benefit c
     WHERE c.isactive = 1
     and c.benefitcode = 'md'
) med on med.employee_id = emp.employee_id
-- optical
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT c.benefitcode, c.employee_id
     FROM employee_benefit c
     WHERE c.isactive = 1
     and c.benefitcode = 'op'
) opt on opt.employee_id = emp.employee_id
-- uniform
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT c.benefitcode, c.employee_id
     FROM employee_benefit c
     WHERE c.isactive = 1
     and c.benefitcode = 'un'
) uni on uni.employee_id = emp.employee_id
-- education
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT c.benefitcode, c.employee_id
     FROM employee_benefit c
     WHERE c.isactive = 1
     and c.benefitcode = 'ed'
) edu on edu.employee_id = emp.employee_id
```

Any clue on what is the best way with best performance?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How can do it with PIVOT instead?

Comment: sorry, where do I have to place the pivot in my script? Thanks a lot

Comment: I see that my answer has been accepted - how is the performance of using the PIVOT?

Comment: Very good from 12 seconds to 0

Comment: I'm glad to hear that - although 12 seconds *run once* shouldn't be an issue at all .. if it's run more than once, I'd start to become a little bit concerned with the design ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, note that this operation actually [*de-normalizes*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) the model and I would *keep the normalized table design* if it were my decision. I'm not sure what "pressure" mandates this situation, but I find that such approaches make the model harder to maintain and use. Such de-normalization *may* slow down queries that could otherwise use indexing on the join table.

That being said, one approach is to use [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), which is an SQL Server (2005+) extension. I've worked up an [example on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/adad5/1). The example needs to be tailored some the actual table schema and benefit values - the pivot is just over the linking (employee_benefit) table in this case. Note the pre-filter on the benefit status to avoid the columns (and thus implicit grouping) from creeping through the PIVOT.

#### Query

```
select pvt.*
from (
  select emp, benefitcode
  from benefits
  where isactive = 1
) as b
pivot (
  -- implicit group by on other columns!
  count (benefitcode)
  -- the set of all values (to turn into columns)
  for benefitcode in ([lf], [md], [op])
) as pvt
```

#### Definition

```
create table benefits (
  emp int,
  isactive tinyint,
  benefitcode varchar(10)
)
go

insert into benefits (emp, isactive, benefitcode)
values
(1, 0, 'lf'), (1, 1, 'md'), (1, 1, 'op'),
(2, 1, 'lf'),
(3, 1, 'lf'), (3, 1, 'md'), (3, 1, 'md')
go
```

#### Result

```
EMP LF  MD  OP
1   0   1   1    -- excludes inactive LF for emp #1
2   1   0   0
3   1   2   0    -- counts multiple benefits
```

Note that, just like with the many left-joins, the benefit data is now *column oriented* over a fixed set of values. Then just manipulate the data from the resulting query (e.g. as done in the original code, but checking for >= 1) to build the desired [bit array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array) value.

#### Will it perform better?

I'm not sure. However, my "initial hunch" is that the query may perform much better if the employee column is indexed but the benefit is not; and it may perform worse given the inverse - [inspect the query plan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) of both approaches to know what SQL Server is *really* doing.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just join to a table that codes the benefits to an integer (Life -> 10000, Medical -> 1000, ..., education -> 1; and then

- Sum the benefit code integer;
- convert the sum to a string;
- prepend the string '0000' and take the right-most 5 characters.

*Update:*

```
select
   EmployeeID,
   right('0000' + convert(varchar(5),sum(map.value)),5)
from (
    select value=10000, benefit = 'Lif' union all
    select value= 1000, benefit = 'Med' union all
    select value=  100, benefit = 'Uni' union all
    select value=   10, benefit = 'Opt' union all
    select value=    1, benefit = 'Edu'
) map
join
   blah blah 
group by EmployeeID
```

Comment: Im not allowed to touch tables. :(

Comment: +1 This is the right idea; you could also use values 1,2,4,8,16 and then extract bits at the end.  The decimal approach works well also.

Answer (score 0):

I like the summing suggestion but I would do it inline like this:

```
Select
   e.employee_id,
   e.Name,
   e.Lastname,
   right('0000' + convert(varchar(5),sum( 
        case 
           when eb.benefitcode is null then 0
           when eb.benefitcode = 'lf' then 10000
           when eb.benefitcode = 'md' then 1000
           when eb.benefitcode = 'op' then 100
           when eb.benefitcode = 'un' then 10
           when eb.benefitcode = 'ed' then 1
        end )),5) benefits
from
   Employee e

   LEFT OUTER JOIN Employee_Benefit eb
      on ( eb.Employee_id = e.Employee_id )
group by
   e.employee_id,
   e.Name,
   e.Lastname
```

Didn't get a chance to try it for syntax but that's the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE (EMPID,EMPNAME,LASTNAME) AS (SELECT D.* FROM TABLENAME_EMP D  WHERE D.EMPID=1), CTE2(BENEFITS) AS ((SELECT SUBSTRING((SELECT ''+ C.BENEFITS FROM (SELECT A.*,B.BEN_ID,CASE WHEN B.BEN_ID IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE '1' END BENEFITS FROM BEN_EMP b JOIN TABLENAME_EMP A ON A.empid=b.empid WHERE b.EMPID IN (1) AND B.ben_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)) C ORDER BY C.BENEFITS FOR XML PATH('')),1,200000) AS BENEFITS))
select * from cte,cte2
```

Comment: If you want to find for all employees then you can change EMPID=1  TO EMPID IN (1,2,3,4,5.....)